# Discrete Uniform Law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

It is said that events are a subset of the sample space because you don't assign probabilities to individual outcomes. In a very simple sample space like that of flipping a fair coin, where the potential outcomes are only H and T, it does feel like you are assigning a probability to individual outcomes..ie. Prob of H and Prob of T.

So, if the sample space of a fair coin flip is H and T, is that a set and a subset? Is that why it makes sense?

Comment: Is it as simple as H and T are a set, and T or H would be the subset?

Comment: If you only flip once then the sample space is $\{H,T\}$ and the four possible events are $\emptyset$, $\{H\}$, $\{T\}$, $\{H,T\}$, i.e. subsets of the sample space.  These can be assigned probabilities.  If you flip a countably infinite number of times to get an infinite sequence, the sample space is  $\{H,T\}^{\mathbb N}$ and except in extreme cases the probability of a particular infinite sequence is $0$ while certain combinations of sequences can be events with probabilities neither $0$ nor $1$

Comment: But you can't get an H and T or an empty set from one flip.

Comment: That is correct, but here $\{H,T\}$ would mean that the flip was an element of $\{H,T\}$ i.e. $H$ or $T$ happened, and that has a probability of $1$.  That may be confusing as in other cases $H,T$ may suggest $H$ and $T$ both happened and, as you implicitly say, that would have probability $0$

Comment: Ah. Is the formula P(A) = number of elements in A/number of points in sample space what you are referring to?

Comment: It depends on whether all the elements of the sample space have equal non-zero probability.  So in general you cannot say that, though in special cases it may be possible

Comment: But Discrete Uniform Law is a special case no?..one where there is a fair coin flip?

Comment: Yes - that is a special case

Comment: But in this special case, only events H and T (subsets) would exist? not the 4?

Comment: The only two possible OUTCOMES are $H$ and $T$, but there are other possible EVENTS.  The event "Either a Heads or Tails is flipped" is $\{H\} \cup \{T\} = \{H,T\}$.  The event "The coin comes up both Heads and Tails at the same time" is $\{H\} \cap \{T\} = \emptyset$.

Comment: That clarifies it. Thanks. But this formula P(A) = number of elements in A/number of points in sample space ..is referring to which one? outcomes or events?

Comment: Probability is a measure of events, and events are sets of outcomes.  *Some* events may indeed be singleton sets (a set with only one element).  There is a difference between $e$ and $\{e\}$; where the former is a outcome, and the later the event of only that outcome.

Comment: Your formula is valid for an unbiased probability space - where the probability measure of any event is proportional to the count for outcomes in that event (ie: the cardinality of the event).